# Dynamic pattern for input field in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I have an input field `driveletterMount`:

```html
<input
    id="labelPath{{ i }}"
    name="labelPath{{i}}"
    type="text"
    #labelPath="ngModel"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="diskItem.labelPath"
    pattern=""
    [disabled]="isDisabled || i<=0"
    [required]
    />
```

Here I need a dynamic pattern for the field with a condition.
For example:

**If the os type is Windows then:**

```
pattern="[0-9][0-9]"
```

**If os is linux then:**

```
pattern="^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$(?<!^\/bin|\/dev|\/etc|\/mnt|\/opt|\/run|\/srv|\/sys|\/tmp|\/usr|\/var|\/lib|\/proc|\/sbin|\/root|\/boot|\/home|\/lib64|\/media|\/usr\/bin|\/usr\/lib|\/usr\/lib64|\/usr\/sbin|(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complex condition that should be handled in the component's TypeScript file. (*.ts)

Add a method to the TS file called, say, `getPattern`:

```
get pattern(): string {
    if (this.osIsWindows) {
        return "[0-9][0-9]";
    } else if (this.osIsLinux) {
        return "^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$(?<!^\/bin|\/dev|\/etc|\/mnt|\/opt|\/run|\/srv|\/sys|\/tmp|\/usr|\/var|\/lib|\/proc|\/sbin|\/root|\/boot|\/home|\/lib64|\/media|\/usr\/bin|\/usr\/lib|\/usr\/lib64|\/usr\/sbin|(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$)";
    } else {
        return ""; // TODO: default value
    }
}

get osIsWindows(): boolean {
    // TODO: implement this
}

get osIsLinux(): boolean {
    // TODO: implement this
}
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<input
             id="labelPath{{ i }}"
             name="labelPath{{i}}"
             type="text"
             #labelPath="ngModel"
             class="form-control"
             [(ngModel)]="diskItem.labelPath"
             [pattern]="pattern"
             [disabled]="isDisabled || i<=0"
             [required]
            />
```

(Footnote: The original version of this answer used a **method** called `getPattern()`. As discussed in the comments, this is nonstandard, so I have updated it to use a `get` accessor.)

Comment: function in html is not good for perfomance. and pattern is not binding then you have to take inside between {{}} but function always listen then not good approach to use if you dont have to listen always

Comment: It depends on the use case. If the condition is something that takes a long time to evaluate, and you can verify at init time and never have to worry about again, then yes, it is more performant to store it to a component variable and just retrieve that. However I can't imagine that the implementations of `osIsLinux`, `osIsWindows`, etc ... will be particularly complex, so I like to prioritise maintainability of the code.

Comment: You're right that I forgot to add `[]` around `pattern`. Fixed.

Comment: @AlexWalker it's not necessarily a question of how long it takes to compute the expression but rather that a method call or accessor reference is opaque to the binding engine and this results in dirty checking. On an unrelated note, an accessor would be more idiomatic than a method.

Comment: @Alex Walker Assigning to a variable is more performant for each case. Because if you use call a function in the template and do not modify change detection strategy of Angular, that method keeps getting invoked over and over again.

Comment: Updated to use accessor instead of method. I wasn't aware that Angular treated them so differently.

Comment: It was a stylistic observation. If you reread my comment, an accessor will negatively impact performance in the same way.

Comment: Personally, I would calculate the value on component construction since it's the OS won't change over the app's lifetime: `class Component { pattern = this.osIsWindows ? /[0-9]{2}/ : this.osIsLinux ? /linux regex.../ : //;}`. Still a solid answer: +1

Comment: For sure, using an accessor/method when a field could be used instead is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what it makes easier though. Just calculate it. You can use an IIFE if you don't want ternary syntax. Also, take advantage of regex literals

Comment: Basically my line of thought was "what piece of knowledge does the OP need to solve this problem". I believe the critical thing was a very basic Angular concept - the fact that this variable `pattern` could be defined in the TypeScript file (rather than HTML) and a definition set up there. So that's what this answer focuses on, primarily. I agree that the actual TS code is not perfect _for the poster's specific case_.

Comment: @AlexWalker what should i use now in HTML [pattern]='getPattern()' or [pattern]='pattern'

Comment: `[pattern]='pattern'` is cleaner.

Comment: @AlexWalker, indeed true. I voted for the answer so I'm not complaining. Just got involved in the discussion.

Comment: can anyone look in to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580184/how-can-i-do-unit-test-for-setinterval-in-ngoninit

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
       this.pattern="[0-9][0-9]";
}
 if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) {
this.pattern="^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$(?<!^\/bin|\/dev|\/etc|\/mnt|\/opt|\/run|\/srv|\/sys|\/tmp|\/usr|\/var|\/lib|\/proc|\/sbin|\/root|\/boot|\/home|\/lib64|\/media|\/usr\/bin|\/usr\/lib|\/usr\/lib64|\/usr\/sbin|(\/usr\/bin)|(\/usr\/lib)|(\/usr\/lib64)|(\/usr\/sbin)$)"
}
```

and in html

```
  <input
             id="labelPath{{ i }}"
             name="labelPath{{i}}"
             type="text"
             #labelPath="ngModel"
             class="form-control"
             [(ngModel)]="diskItem.labelPath"
             pattern="{{pattern}}"
             [disabled]="isDisabled || i<=0"
             [required]
            />
```