# how can i do unit test for setInterval in ngoninit?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have a refresh() function which executes the updated data scenario, here what i'm trying to achieve is for every 1min it has to refresh automatically without user interaction, so where i'm using setinterval in ngoninit so that i can executes for every 60 sec and i'm clearing those interval in **ngDestroy**;
Here is the component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): any {
 this.refresh();
 this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                      if (this.hideLog) {
                        this.updateWorkflow();
                      } else {
                        this.refresh();
                      }
                  },                            60000); 

}



ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.clearInt();
}
clearInt(): void {
  if (this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

How can i add test for this in my spec.ts file so that **ngonint** test describe should pass

Error while running my test case:

> Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.

can anyone help me on this

Comment: Have a look at `fakeAsync` and `flush` or `tick`. Also I advice you to make the interval run outside of the `ngZone`, and go back in when necessary

Comment: checked with adding fakeasync, flush and tick too, still facing same issue. moved this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                      if (this.hideLog) {
                        this.updateWorkflow();
                      } else {
                        this.refresh();
                      }
                  },                            60000);  to new function and calling that function in ngoninit but, still facing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm achieving bellow error with following code after my **expect** of the test case ✌

> Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue

```
 spyOn(window, 'setInterval').and.callThrough();

 flush();
 flushMicrotasks();
 discardPeriodicTasks();
```